# Do I need to create tablespace and also add all datafiles before importing a schema using datapump?

Tags: oracle-11g, datapump

Do I need to create tablespace and also add all datafiles before importing a schema using datapump? Or does impdp add all data files itself first and then unloads data into it?

Answer (score 3):

`impdp` is able to create the tablespaces. You can even change the location of the datafiles if needed. Check [the documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/server.111/b28319/dp_import.htm) for more information since there are many parameters with this tool (**REMAP_DATAFILES** and **REUSE_DATAFILES** for example).

Answer (score 0):

You need to do the following:

- User is created (create user blah identified by blah:)
- Create the tablespace (create tablespace blah...)
- Put dmp file in dmp directly (usually installation home directly/admin/dpdump)  unless you create your own then you'll need to go into sqlplus and create the directory object and use that object as a parameter in impdp (DIRECTORY=myDirObject)
- Then run impdpd. It will not create the tablespaces for you in my experience.